# calling a cpp class without headers

Tags: c++

I have the following class that is in file called fooTest.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class foo
{
private:
    float price;
public:
    foo():price(0){}
    foo(float p)
    {
        price=p;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout<<price;
    }
};
```

and my main program is in another file called test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    int main(void)
    {
        foo p1;
            p1.print();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
```

The problem it does not recognize the object p1, why is that? I do not want to use a header in this program

sidenote: I am using Visual C++, and both files are in the same Source Files folder

Comment: What is your reason for avoiding using headers?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think it should be a valid reference?  Test.cpp knows nothing about the other cpp file at compile time.  It is only when you link your object modules together, that references can be resolved.  You need to use a header.  That is a standard practice.

Answer (score 2):

** *The problem it does not recognize the object p1, why is that?** *

When you compile a source module, the only thing a compiler sees is what you give it in that module.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    foo p1;
    p1.print();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Where do you see any definition of foo?  You don't see it, and neither does the compiler.  The compiler sees "foo p1;" and says to you "what is a foo?"

** *sidenote: I am using Visual C++, and both files are in the same Source Files folder* **

If you thought that the compiler will do a directory search for your other modules to figure out these unknown types, then you're mistaken.  C++ doesn't work that way -- it compiles what it is given, therefore you must tell the compiler what a foo is before you can start to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always include fooTest.cpp directly to your test.cpp, and compile directly with

```
gcc test.cpp
```

But then again, why would you not use header for that? And compile regularly like

```
gcc test.cpp fooTest.cpp
```

And, how do you expect it to compile correctly without any reference to fooTest.cpp

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a class that hasn't been defined.  One way or another, the compiler must see the definition of `class foo` while compiling `test.cpp`.

You can accomplish that by moving it into a header, *or* you can just copy and paste the class definition into `test.cpp`.  But copying it is a bad idea, because then when you make changes to the class in the future, you have to make each change in both places.  The class must always be defined the same way in all files where it's seen.

This is exactly what header files are for:  making the same code in multiple source files without having to maintain multiple identical copies of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the class declaration in each source file that references or defines an object based on that class. The standard way to do this is to place class declarations in a header file so that the declarations for a given named class are identical.

If you don't want to include the class declaration in a header file, then simply include the class declaration in each source file that references it. In your case, copy

```
class foo
{
/* the rest of your fooy guts */
};
```

into test.cpp.

Are you a Java programmer, by any chance? Java handles this in a more automatic fashion than C++, unfortunately.